# Using wildcard does not resolve sub of subdomain

Tags: bind, subdomain, a-record, wildcard-subdomain

I have a domain `xyz.com` on (**xx.xxx.255.25**) and `sub.xyz.com` on (**xx.xxx.255.240**)
To resolve `sub` I added the following reocrd in BIND

> `sub       IN     A      xx.xxx.255.240` 
> `*.sub     IN     A      xx.xxx.255.240`

and worked well, but the problem is with the sub of subdomain it did not resolve.
I tried adding a `test` sub and worked well:

> `test.sub       IN     A      xx.xxx.255.240`

The point of the wildcard (*) is that I have multiple subs (`FTP, mail, SMTP...`)
So where exactly I did wrong caused the sub of the subdomain to not resolve?

#### [UPDATE]

Resolving sub of subdomains worked as *@Tommiie* said, but the second problem appeared is with `TXT` records (SPF, DKIM, DMARC), Can I add wildacrd as `A records` to resolve them?

Comment: Normally bind is configured to allow shorthand and unqualified resource records (those whose name does not end in a `.` dot) get appended with the zone name. A record `host` in the `example.com.` zone file will have the name of the zone appended and be processed as `host.example.com.` Your question mentions record `sub.`  with a trailing dot. Those are FQDN’s and won’t have the zone name appended.

Comment: even after removing the dot at the end I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have other records in the `sub` subdomain?

> The wildcard character matches any number of labels in a name as long as there isn't an exact match with a name already in the name server's database.

Quote from DNS & BIND (5th edition), p. 488

As you also want TXT wildcard records:

```
*.sub.example.com.  A     xx.xxx.255.240
*.sub.example.com.  TXT   "spv record"
*.sub.example.com.  TXT   "dkim record"
*.sub.example.com.  TXT   "more text records"
```

Please share a more complete configuration.

PS: remove the trailing dots. It wont work with them in place.

Comment: In the server **xx.xxx.255.240** where `sub` is, there are different records but why it matters?

Comment: If you have ``test.sub.<domain>.`` then ``*.sub.<domain>`` will never hit.

Comment: so I need to delete `test` and it must work well, right? but what about **TXT** records?

Comment: Since you create a wildcard for an A record, it only goes for A records. TXT records can remain in the database.

Comment: @AragonS: if your issue fixed? Or is it still not working?

Comment: for `A records` it worked but I am trying to add `SPF, DMARC, DKIM`, but **TXT records** do not resolve

Comment: Please update your question with your current configuration.

Comment: just update it!

Comment: Add a wildcard TXT record similar to the wildcard A record.

Comment: so it should be `*.sub.     IN     TXT        xx.xxx.255.240`, right?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Just to be sure, by "SPF record" you mean just a quote or the actual record?

Comment: no... you enter your SPF record there.